# ¿Porqué sucede esto al insertar un dato ($variable) de PHP a SQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
    $respuesta = $conexion->query("SELECT nombre FROM jugadores WHERE id = 
    '1';");
    $fila = $respuesta->fetch_row();
    $nombredeBD = $fila[0];
    echo $nombredeBD;//resultado: Ab

    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"]; 
    $nombre = preg_replace('/[\r\n|\n|\r|""]+/', PHP_EOL, $nombre);
    echo $nombre; //resultado: Ab
    $nombremas = $nombre . "_48536"; 
    echo $nombremas;//resultado: Ab_48536
```

Primera prueba de que no funciona a pesar de que el "echo" lo muestra:

```
    if($nombredeBD == $nombre){
    echo "funciona";
    }else{
    echo "no funciona";//este es el resultado
    }
```

NO funciona

```
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion,"utf8");   
    $insertam14 = $conexion->query("INSERT INTO `jugadores` (`id`, 
    `nombremas`, `nombre`) VALUES (NULL, '$nombremas', '$nombre');");
```

Y luego al insertar en la base de datos se guarda de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

NO está centrado el "$nombre"... el "id" y el "$nombremas" si estan centrados.
¿Alguien a pasado por esto? ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema está aquí:

`preg_replace('/[\r\n|\n|\r|""]+/', PHP_EOL, $nombre);`

El segundo parámetro de la función `preg_replace($patrón, $sustitución, $cadena)` es usado para **sustituir la coincidencia de algún caracter del patrón (*primer parámetro*) en la cadena de texto (*tercer parámetro*)**.

Por lo tanto, asumo que te está sustituyendo algún caracter por un salto de línea `PHP_EOL` **(*End Of Line*)**, el cual es tu segundo parámetro.

[Aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php) la docu de la función en la pagina oficial de `php`

Comment: Encontré el problema y la solución. El problema es que para un proyecto anterior, antes de recibir el $_POST, lo estaba enviando en cadena de caracteres "JSON" y "send" javascript . Solo le quité el JSON.stringify() y listo. O también puedo "decodificar" con json_decode. En el proyecto anterior enviaba un array y por ello lo ocupaba. Muchas gracias